# An exercise with distribution, ODE and principal value

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm in trouble with this exercise:

*If T $\in D’$ is a solution of the equation $xT'=-T$ then I have to prove that there exists a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the distribution $P=T-C \cdot PV(1/x)$ is zero in $\mathbb{R}$ without the origin. After that, I have to prove that $P$ is supported in zero and, using this fact, to find all solutions to the above equation.*

Firstly I proved that if $T$ solves the above equation then $T$ solves also $(xT)'=0$ but I don't know if this could be usefull. But know I'm stuck.
Some ideas?

Here $PV(1/x)$ is the principal value of $(1/x)$ and it is such that $\langle PV(1/x),\phi\rangle := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\epsilon,\epsilon)} (1/x)\phi(x)dx$

where $\phi$ is a test function

Comment: "_If $T \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ is a solution of the equation $xT'=-T$_"
Is there even such a solution? Or should it be $T \in \mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: My apologies, you are right

Comment: If $<P,\phi>=0$ for every $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R} \setminus 0)$, can I say that this holds for $x\phi$ too?

Comment: @md2perpe of course; $T\equiv0$ =)

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is correct; indeed $(xT')=0$. It implies that $xT = C$ for a constant $A$ (this is an exercise covered in all textbooks and on Math.SE).

Now consider $S=T - C\cdot PV(1/x)$ and take $\phi\in D$ such that $supp\, \phi$ is separated from zero. What can you say about $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$? 
What happens when we apply $$\langle S ,\phi\rangle =\left \langle S, x \cdot \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\right\rangle?$$